# How to do a rebase with git gui?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-gui

I know how to do a git rebase from the command line, but how do you do it with the official [git-gui](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gui.html)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add this to the `.gitconfig` file in your home directory to add rebase commands to the Tools menu:

```
[guitool "Rebase onto..."]
    cmd = git rebase $REVISION
    revprompt = yes
[guitool "Rebase/Continue"]
    cmd = git rebase --continue
[guitool "Rebase/Skip"]
    cmd = git rebase --skip
[guitool "Rebase/Abort"]
    cmd = git rebase --abort
[guitool "Pull with Rebase"]
    cmd = git pull --rebase
```

Comment: To the cmd line (2nd line), you need to add $REVISION, i.e. cmd = git rebase $REVISION.  Otherwise, thanks!  I had no idea this capability existed.

Comment: Interactive rebase is also possible, you just have to set the env-var EDITOR to a gui editor. I considered this too much of an edit to add to your answer so I created my own -- feel free to add my answer to yours.

Comment: Some window appears, but what to enter in these fields?

Comment: I found Jim Raden's comment to be correct, $REVISION is required instead of $VERSION. Perhaps Ted Percival could edit his answer? I'd do it but I am not sure if $REVISION is universally correct, or platform specific or something.

Answer (score 17):

In `git-gui`:

1. Go to `Tools -> Add` and then enter a custom command i.e. `git rebase master`.
2. Select *Add globally* to have this option appear for all repositories. (It will write the configuration to your `~/.gitconfig` for you, as @Ted-Percival mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9200135/808044)).

Comment: Worth pointing out that your local Git database must be up-to-date with changes of the branch you wish to rebase onto. If the local `master` has not been updated since you branched, `git rebase master` does nothing! To resolve this, first run `git checkout master; git pull; git checkout MY_BRANCH` from the command-line, or change the `git-gui` command to `git rebase origin\master`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a full interactive rebase with `git gui`, complete with commit selection, rewording and conflict resolution! In addition to Ted Percival's answer, Add this to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[guitool "Rebase interactive"]
    cmd = EDITOR=gvim git rebase -i $REVISION
    revprompt = yes
```

You *must* use a graphical editor -- plain old `vim` won't work, but `gvim` will. You may use any gui editor, I use `nedit` for example. A separate window of this editor will pop-up any time you need to input something: initially selecting commits, rewording commit messages (whether for reword or squash commits), etc.

Answer (score 3):

`git gui` can be used to add files to the index when doing a `rebase --interactive` (as mention in the[`git rebase` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), The [GitHub rebase help page](http://help.github.com/rebase/) or in this [git rebase interactive tip article](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/12/10/git-interactive-rebase-tips/)), but not to perform the `rebase` itself.
(unless, as you saw, you define the command yourself in the Tools section)