# Is there a way to make GitHub Desktop rebase a branch against master?

Tags: github-for-mac

When I choose **"update from master"**, it creates a merge commit. I'd rather just have it re-base. Is this possible?

Comment: I think one solution can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830344/how-to-do-a-rebase-with-git-gui

Comment: @BrandonLee I'm not sure they are talking about the same program as him.

Comment: It looks like Github Desktop has rebase now.

Answer (score 29):

It does not appear that feature is currently included in GitHub desktop. What I normally do is click on the repository name in the drop-down menu in the top left and then click on "open in terminal". Then just follow the instructions [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

---

#### Update:

If you add this to your `.gitconfig`, GitHub desktop should rebase according to [here](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3422#issuecomment-467948996).

```
[pull]
    rebase = true
```

---

### Second Update:

GitHub desktop 2.0 now supports rebasing built in! It is under the branch section of the top menu or you can use the shortcut `⇧⌘E`

Comment: You can also use the `Ctrl + \`` combination

Answer (score 9):

As @Taraz commented on the question, GitHub Desktop now has the option built in.

`Branch > Rebase current branch`

It's below the `Update from master` option

Answer (score 1):

> Using `rebase` instead of merging branches results in an easier to follow but less exact history of commits. Your team should agree under what circumstances you should `rebase` a branch. You should still always merge branches into the main branch through a pull request.
>
> A suggested approach is to allow rebasing local changes that you have made but haven't shared with others, but to merge once you are sharing changes with others. This avoids trouble with rewriting history while still letting you easily catch up with changes as you develop your code locally.

## Ref & Source:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/rebase?tabs=visual-studio#when-to-rebase-vs-merge
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/pulling?tabs=visual-studio#update-your-branch-with-the-latest-changes-from-master

Comment: The suggestion in your quote's second paragraph is exactly what this question is asking *how* to do in GitHub Desktop - not add a noisey merge commit every time you update unshared local changes against master. I think GitHub Desktop on Windows uses the suggested approach by default but on Mac it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

No. There was a [feature request](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1652) on their GitHub issue tracker for exactly this option a year ago, for which [the response](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1652#issuecomment-312099782) was

> This idea is interesting for the future, but this is beyond the scope of our current roadmap.

Since then, [another feature request](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3422), which is still open, has also been posted.