# Is it possible to git pull within GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have two GitHub profiles (one for work and one for personal), and sometimes I'd fork a repo on GitHub, and edit it right on GitHub to send a pull request.

But is it possible to do a `git pull` inside of GitHub?  Otherwise I think the state of that cloned repo is the same as when I cloned it (say, 2 weeks ago), and I'd hope to keep it updated to the current source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep a GitHub fork up to date without a merge commit or using CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409392/how-to-keep-a-github-fork-up-to-date-without-a-merge-commit-or-using-cli)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+update+forked+repository+web-ui

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56437733/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853061/7976758